# How do I display real-time firebase data on my website?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to post the data from a moisture sensor on a website. I am using Arduino to update and send the data to a Real-Time Firebase database. From there I am using Glitch.com for my website. I am using a moisture sensor, and have the variable 'Moisture' in my database where the values are stored and updated every 0.3 seconds. I currently have the following code:

**HTML File**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.11.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.11.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.11.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.11.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.11.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.11.0/firebase-messaging.js"></script>

    <script>
      // Initialize Firebase
      var config = {
        apiKey: "xx",
    authDomain: "xx",
    databaseURL: "xx",
    projectId: "xx",
    storageBucket: "xx",
    messagingSenderId: "xx",
    appId: "xx"
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
    </script>


  <script>

    var database = firebase.database();


    var ref = firebase.database().ref("plant-patrol/Moisture");
    ref.once("value")
    .then(function(snapshot) {
    var key = snapshot.key; // "plant-patrol"
    var childKey = snapshot.child("plant-patrol/Moisture").key; // "Moisture"
    });
  </script>

<script>
    var ref = firebase.database().ref("plant-patrol/Moisture");
ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
   console.log(snapshot.val());
}, function (error) {
   console.log("Error: " + error.code);
});
    </script>  

    <script src="/script.js" defer></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

**JS File**

```
auth.onAuthStateChanged(currentUser => console.log(currentUser));

auth.signInAnonymously();
```

I have no idea what this JS code does, but I copied it from another question on Stack Overflow.

Now as stated before, the path in the Realtime Firebase db I want to display is 'Moisture', that is also the only data in the db. I have tried messing around a bit with the childkey and snapshot, and tried reading into what they actually do. Sadly I was not able to display any form of data, not even in the console.

The read & write lines in Firebase have both been set to True as security is not relevant (school project). I was also wondering if it is possible to update the data on the website without having to refresh the page.

### Update

Made a bit of progress,read my comments below!

Comment: Also just noticed that for line 3 in JS and line 47 in the HTML file, it's both logging null in the console.

Comment: Another breakthrough, after removing the "plant-patrol/Moisture" from the second var ref, it now shows the data in the console. However, when I want to display the value in the console with a document.write(snapshot.val()), it displays [object Object], and not the actual values.

Comment: Question is still open, sadly have not figured out how to fix the object Object thing. It's also displaying [object Object] next to each other, filling the screen. I am looking for a single value that gets updated, preferably without having to refresh the page, but I'm not sure if that's even possible.

Comment: Warning: your API key is still visible in the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60759569/revisions). Make sure it is invalidated at your API provider.